# How to set up secure websocket on Meteor app (localhost)

Tags: meteor, wss, ddp

I used [Asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) as my ddp to connect with my Meteor app as backend. The front end run `https` and it works perfectly on Chrome. So it actually a consist of two separate apps run independently. But it didn't go well in Safari. Safari block the connection as there are mix/insecure content.

So far I have `force-ssl` package added to my Meteor app but still no luck. How do I enable `wss` protocol on my local development machine (**localhost**)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to connect on localhost by just using http://localhost:3000? If your Meteor backend and frontend are both running on localhost then you shouldn't be trying to connect via https or wss. Your machine doesn't have a trusted certificate running on it so the connection can't be made.

Also, don't use force-ssl locally for the same reason I mention above.

Please post the full error from Safari if the above solution doesn't work. Please clarify what is running where (are they both on localhost, or just one).

Comment: Yes both are running localhost. I can generate self sign cert as well and I really need the secure layer because browser cannot accept mixed content

Comment: Even a self signed cert won't work here since it won't be trusted. You don't need force-ssl, instead use something like nginx or apache to force ssl when you are hosting your app. Then in your dev environment remove the force-ssl package and it should work for you.

Comment: @JoshJoe I am facing the similar issue and I have posted it on stackoverflow, not getting any responses. Can you please have a look at it ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430122/uncaught-typeerror-a-qs-unescape-is-not-a-function

Comment: @AnoopGoudar I replied there