# wss://my.domain.com/sockjs/362/4q059yw7/websocket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssl, nginx, meteor

I  need help in fixing this issue.

I am trying to implement ssl to the domain my.domain.com

Front end is Angular and Backend is Meteor

I was able to create ssl certificates properly and was able to get **Secure https** label on loading the domain, but the page was not rendering because of the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: a._qs.unescape is not a function
```

from the build file in the .build/dist/bundle/programs/web.browser

```
Request URL:https://my.domain.com/5a0c202b90aa3cc1c9414b703c4e1f343fb0dd4e.js?meteor_js_resource=true
```

Below websocket request will remain pending with **status 101**

```
wss://my.domain.com/sockjs/362/4q059yw7/websocket
```

I have not written any code on Meteor to run it to https, I am trying to handle through nginx. 
From angular after adding ssl certificates trying to connect to meteor through`wss://localhost/` instead of `ws://localhost:3000/`

Please find my nginx file below.

```
events {    
}

http {
  server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
     server_name  my.domain.com;
     root   /client;
     index  index.html;

     location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
     }
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

 server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
     server_name  my.domain.com;

     root   /client;
     index  index.html;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /uploadFile {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /51x.html {
        root   /client;
    }
  }  
}
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Did all your scripts load? Feels like there's a js file that didn't get loaded properly. Does the debugger show any 404s during page load?

Comment: No 404 error messages, but the in the network tab websocket status would always remain as pending.
If proxy settings from nginx file, then I dont get 'Uncaught TypeError: a._qs.unescape is not a function' error

Comment: Did I make any mistake in nginx ? Nginx file works fine without proxy settings for wws connection

Comment: I'm confused about the NGINX rule you have here. Is this the whole thing? There should be one part for Meteor and another for Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue I had.
Issue was in below line in nginx.

```
 proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
```

I fixed it by redirecting it to `http://localhost:3000/websocket;` and location `as location /websocket`

Snippet is below.

```
location /websocket {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/websocket;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```