# Spring websocket (WSS) with angular sockjs (HTTPS) over secure web socket server (tomcat)

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm working on sending messages from the server side to angular client application using Spring web socket + stomp + SockJsClient at server side and SockJS at the angular side.

My Socket server is a spring boot application and running on 8080 port.

Its working fine over ws/http protocol. but now I have enabled SSL on socket server.

**Socket Server configuration.**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/topic");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/sync").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}}
```

**Working code of Java Client over WS**

```
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>(1);
transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());

WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
String url = "ws://my-socket.server.com/sync";
StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler(senderId, syncUrl, content);
stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler);
```

**Working code of angular client over HTTP**

```
const Stomp = StompJs.Stomp;
const socket = new SockJS('http://my-socket.server.com/sync');
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
this.stompClient.connect({}, (res, err) => {}
```

Now I have implement SSL over my web socket server which is running on separate spring boot server. And update Protocol at server and client side like. **ws to wss and http to https.**

And also try following things to add SSL Context

```
StandardWebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>(1);
Map<String, Object> userProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
userProperties.put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", SSLContext.getDefault());
simpleWebSocketClient.setUserProperties(userProperties);
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(simpleWebSocketClient));
```

I have take reference from following stack link but no luck :(

[Secure websocket with HTTPS (SSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430122/wss-my-domain-com-sockjs-362-4q059yw7-websocket)

[How to use Spring WebSocketClient with SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177803/how-to-use-spring-websocketclient-with-ssl)

Please help me to get out of it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Any updates? Have the same problem.

Comment: I am looking for same solution? any updates?

Comment: Have you tried with updated js - sock code https one?

Comment: @John what is the issue your are facing here?

Comment: I have the same problem :/ As soon as I've enabled SSL I can't connect to WebSocket from the client

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console ? Please be specific about the error that you're getting while connection.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same issue , later found I didn't allow end points in security configuration file , just  allow  the websocket endpoint in antMatchers

Answer (score 0):

WE pass through the same problem, first remove withSockJS like

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfigurer implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/js");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

our frontend is in VUE but the connection still the same in JS like.

```js
    WEB_SOCKET_URL_PREFIX: 'ws://localhost:8080/'

    connect(resolve) {
        const URL = '/somePath';
        this.webSocket = new WebSocket(HttpConfig.WEB_SOCKET_URL_PREFIX);
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.webSocket, { debug: false });

        this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
            this.stompClient.subscribe(URL, data => {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

and in your java code you can send the modification with

```java
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

public void someMethod(){

...
 simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/somePath", "someContent");

...
}
```